# Chatbot: Trying to understand Interactive Learning

Tags: chatbot, rasa-core

**Doubts:**

1. It seems that interactive learning completely ignored pre-defined
   stories.
2. How do I create multiple stories with interactive learning? Would have to make a way "happy", generate the file, start a new training
   and then join the files? I tried to fix multiple paths, in the file
   generated by the end it seems to have become a single story.

---

I'm working with Rasa Core, to create context conversations in a chatbot. First I did [this basic tutorial](https://core.rasa.com/tutorial_basics.html) and then tried to make a story file using markers, to make sure I understood how to use markers.

**stories.md** - It looks like this:

```
## Story Hi
* greet           
  - utter_greet

## Story Good Morning
* mood_great
  - utter_happy

## Story bad_day 
* mood_unhappy
  - utter_cheer_up
  - utter_did_that_help
> marking_bad_day

## Story bad_day Best
> marking_bad_day
* mood_affirm
  - utter_happy

## Story bad_day nothing changed
> marking_bad_day
* mood_deny
  - utter_goodbye

## say goodbye
* goodbye
  - utter_goodbye
```

But by testing the conversations with the robot, he does not seem to follow the markers. So I mixed the learning of the third tutorial, which is using interactive learning. This seems to have solved my problem, I really managed to make the bot follow the flow wanted, unfortunately with a great effort of learning.

New **stories.md**:

```
## Generated Story 5325363759313905425
* greet
    - utter_greet
* mood_unhappy
    - utter_cheer_up
    - utter_did_that_help
* mood_affirm
    - utter_happy
* greet
    - utter_greet
* mood_unhappy
    - utter_cheer_up
    - utter_did_that_help
* mood_affirm
    - utter_happy
* greet
    - utter_greet
* mood_unhappy
    - utter_cheer_up
    - utter_did_that_help
* mood_deny
    - export
```

Answer (score 2):

after you finished online training, type `0` to export dialogue and then enter filename (eg. `story01.md`). Now open trained story (`story01.md`) and copy/paste to `data/stories.md` or wherever you stored your `stories.md` training file.

Can you provide your `train_online.py` file maybe?